# Cypress Assert color

Tags: wordpress, testing, cypress

I have the following html structure:

```
   <path d="M16,1 C7.7146,1 1,7.65636364 1,15.8648485 C1,24.0760606 16,51 16,51 C16,51 31,24.0760606 31,15.8648485 C31,7.65636364 24.2815,1 16,1 L16,1 Z" fill="#0fb500"></path>
```

I should state that the color inside fill is # 0fb500. i tried like this but it doesn't work:

```
cy.get('path').should('have.css', 'fill', '#0fb500')
```

gives following error:
[image]

he just says he can't find it

if instead I put:

```
cy.get('path').eq(0).invoke('attr', 'fill').should('contain', '#0fb500')
```

gives following error:
[image]

if i put

```
cy.log(cy.get('path'))
```

obtain: Object(5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try instead of css, using the invoke attribute feature in cypress to find fill and check its value, something like this:

```
cy.get('path').eq(4).should('have.attr', 'fill', '#0fb500')
```

Comment: gives following error:invoke
.attr(fill)
7
AssertionError Timed out retrying: object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but undefined given

Comment: Do you have more than one path in your web page ? If yes which one you are trying to access.

Comment: i copied the element selector with chrome but nothing.

Comment: Can you try by adding `eq(0)`, `cy.get('path').eq(0).invoke('attr', 'fill').should('contain', '#0fb500')`

Comment: following error: Timed out retrying: object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but undefined given. gives error by invoke

Comment: I have replaced `contains` with `have.value`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223143/discussion-between-alapan-das-and-gianmarco-gagliardi).